# Radio buttons to see which fragment is selected strange behaviour

Tags: android, android-fragments, radio-button

I am struggling to find why my radio buttons are not selected in the correct order in my fragment activity. I am trying to use radio buttons to keep track of which fragment is selected. But they seem to get checked at random.

My xml for the fragment activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.partyfind.ScreenSlidePagerActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/alipay_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/taobao_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioGroup
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/selector_1"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:button="@null"
            android:background="@drawable/radio_button_slide_indicator"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/selector_2"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:button="@null"
            android:background="@drawable/radio_button_slide_indicator"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/selector_3"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:button="@null"
            android:background="@drawable/radio_button_slide_indicator"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/selector_4"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:button="@null"
            android:background="@drawable/radio_button_slide_indicator"/>
        </RadioGroup>
    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/facebook_btn_login"
        fb:login_text="Login with Facebook"
        fb:logout_text="Log out of Facebook"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="We wont post on your behalf"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My FragmentStatePagerAdapter :

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.v("Position"," "+String.valueOf(position));

        switch(position) {
            case 0: selector(0); return Fragment1.newInstance();
            case 1: selector(1); return Fragment2.newInstance();
            case 2: selector(2); return Fragment3.newInstance();
            case 3: selector(3); return Fragment4.newInstance();
            default:selector(0); return Fragment1.newInstance();
        }
    }
    public void selector(int position){
        RadioButton selector_1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.selector_1);
        RadioButton selector_2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.selector_2);
        RadioButton selector_3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.selector_3);
        RadioButton selector_4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.selector_4);
        if (position == 0){
            resetSelector();
            selector_1.setChecked(true);
        }
        if (position == 1){
            resetSelector();
            selector_2.setChecked(true);
        }
        if (position == 2){
            resetSelector();
            selector_3.setChecked(true);
        }
        if (position == 3){
            resetSelector();
            selector_4.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
    public void resetSelector(){
        RadioButton selector_1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.selector_1);
        RadioButton selector_2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.selector_2);
        RadioButton selector_3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.selector_3);
        RadioButton selector_4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.selector_4);
        selector_1.setChecked(false);
        selector_2.setChecked(false);
        selector_3.setChecked(false);
        selector_4.setChecked(false);


    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it here is the code if any one needs it

**Code**

```
   private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch(position) {
            case 0: return Fragment1.newInstance();
            case 1: return Fragment2.newInstance();
            case 2: return Fragment3.newInstance();
            case 3: return Fragment4.newInstance();
            default:return Fragment1.newInstance();
        }
    }
    public void selector(int position){
        RadioButton selector_1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.selector_1);
        RadioButton selector_2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.selector_2);
        RadioButton selector_3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.selector_3);
        RadioButton selector_4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.selector_4);
        if (position == 0){
            selector_1.setChecked(true);
        }
        if (position == 1){
            selector_2.setChecked(true);
        }
        if (position == 2){
            selector_3.setChecked(true);
        }
        if (position == 3){
            selector_4.setChecked(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        selector(mPager.getCurrentItem());
        return 4;
    }
}
```